# auto refresh using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to auto refresh using jquery. but my page won't reload by itself

Here is my controller:

```
class Count_controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() 
  { 
    $this->load->view('count_view', @a);
  }

  public function table()
  {
    $a = rand(1000, 5000);
    echo $a;
  }
}
```

And here my view:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval("auto_refresh_function();", 500);
        function auto_refresh_function() {
          $('#load_content').load('http://demo1.com/demo/count_controller/table');
        }
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="load_content">Loading</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|js|css|gif|png|jpg|robots\.txt|html)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

can somebody help me?

thank you

Comment: any error in the `console` ? is CSRF on ?

Comment: no, there is no error in console. what is CSRF?

Comment: Any reason not to just do it in a meta tag? <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval();` expects an anonymous function to be present. This anonymous function can then call the function you need.

Try it like this:

```
setInterval(function(){auto_refresh_function();}, 500);
```

Comment: or simply `setInterval(auto_refresh_function, 500);`